# Asymptotic formula for binary bracelets (turnover necklaces)

Tags: co.combinatorics

A "binary bracelet" of length $n$ is a binary string of length $n$; and two binary bracelets are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by rotation or reflection.

The number of different binary bracelets of length $n$ is $B_2(n)$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_bracelets

We cannot find an asymptotic formula for $B_2(n)$ in the literature; is such a formula known?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000029 gives an explicit formula in terms of summation and the Euler totient function, probably you can turn this into an asymptotic. If you look at the logarithmic scatterplot (drawn up to 300) it looks like a nice exponential.

Comment: Looks like $(1/n)2^{n-1}$ plus terms of lower order. E.g., $B_2(30)=17920860$, $(1/30)2^{29}=17895697$ (to the nearest integer).

Comment: @Gerry of course: other terms in the formula from Jukka's link are much less.

Comment: Gerry's rough formula makes sense, because one would expect that if $n$ is large, then almost all $n$-bit strings are rigid in the sense of not being their own rotations or reflections. (Similar to large graphs being rigid etc.) So if you take the $2^n$ bitstrings, you just halve (for reflection) and divide by $n$ (for rotation) and you have the number of bracelets. So you get Gerry's formula. This goes wrong only in the (asymptotically small) set of bitstrings that are not rigid.